# Exportar summary() como data-frame

Tags: r

Quero exportar o summary() do meu data-frame para ficar da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso, construí meu código conforme mostrado abaixo:

```
dados1 <- read.csv("dados-originais.csv", header = T, skip = 0, sep = ",")
summary(dados1)
dados1_summary <- as.data.frame(apply(dados1,2,summary))

> dput(head(dados1,10))
structure(list(Ano1990 = c(8.9, 32.7, 0.3, 3.9, 8.8, 29.2, 2.5, 
0.6, 27.7, 11.2), Ano1991 = c(0, 46.2, 0, 0, 2.8, 3.6, 20.1, 
9.3, 16.3, 11.1), Ano1992 = c(0, 0, 0, 50.1, 2.4, 3.6, 17.1, 
0, 0, 1.2), Ano1993 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.4, 16.5, 0, 1.5), 
    Ano1994 = c(0, 1, 46.6, 25.5, 2.9, 0.2, 3.3, 17.9, 10.7, 
    3), Ano1995 = c(36.3, 35.5, 76.6, 8.6, 27.2, 6.7, 0, 0, 0.3, 
    0), Ano1996 = c(24.6, 10.1, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34.4, 3.8, 38.9
    ), Ano1997 = c(4.8, 12.2, 52.8, 26, 4.4, 0.6, 10.2, 0.2, 
    0, 26.6), Ano1998 = c(1.8, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 12.6, 6, 14.9
    ), Ano1999 = c(0.7, 1.4, 0.6, 26, 14, 1.7, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 5.2
    ), Ano2000 = c(4.9, 18.7, 27.5, 67.2, 5.9, 17.9, 2.5, 12.5, 
    3.8, 3.4), Ano2001 = c(2.1, 1.8, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 33.8, 20.9, 
    7.8), Ano2002 = c(0.4, 12.6, 0, 0, 13.9, 22.9, 27.6, 2.5, 
    16.7, 18.2), Ano2003 = c(0, 18.6, 0, 3.3, 18.3, 4.2, 9.8, 
    6.1, 1, 7.4), Ano2004 = c(0, 8, 2.6, 0.1, 0.5, 16, 3.2, 42.6, 
    11.1, 0.3), Ano2005 = c(0, 0.1, 0.6, 9.9, 5.8, 2.8, 33.4, 
    1, 46.8, 0), Ano2006 = c(0, 0, 0, 6.2, 0.6, 12.5, 1, 19.4, 
    16.3, 20.3), Ano2007 = c(0.2, 10.2, 14.5, 49, 0, 16.3, 8.4, 
    0, 0, 0), Ano2008 = c(0, 0, 2.2, 1.5, 0, 0, 22.5, 0, 23.5, 
    37.7), Ano2009 = c(0, 0, 0, 10.6, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32), Ano2010 = c(20.8, 
    18.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 10, 0.8, 0), Ano2011 = c(45, 15.4, 
    15.9, 43.6, 0.2, 16.1, 4.5, 0, 28.8, 0), Ano2012 = c(18.4, 
    51.5, 45.6, 0, 0, 1, 24.6, 0, 13.6, 71.7), Ano2013 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 4.3, 5.5, 0, 7.8, 0, 0, 2.3), Ano2014 = c(0, 0, 9.6, 
    0, 0, 0, 9.4, 9.6, 0, 0), Ano2015 = c(0.6, 0, 30.8, 3.7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Ano2016 = c(0, 3.2, 0, 35, 33, 5.6, 1.4, 
    5.4, 3.8, 3.4), Ano2017 = c(0, 0, 0, 23.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), Ano2018 = c(0, 0, 1.5, 0, 1, 2.6, 17, 11, 12, 1.5), Ano2019 = c(22.7, 
    0, 2, 0, 59.3, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Contudo, aparece o erro:

```
> dados1_summary <- as.data.frame(apply(dados1,2,summary))
Error in dimnames(x) <- dnx : 'dimnames' applied to non-array
```

Alguma sugestão de como solucionar?

Obs.: Em meu data-frame original cada coluna possui quantidade de dados diferentes e como ele é extenso ao utilizar o dput(head) as colunas ficaram com quantidade de dados padronizadas, não sei se pode haver influência, por isso coloco esse apontamento.

Comment: Bruna, boa noite! A forma que você postou, fazendo um teste rápido aqui parece que funcionou. Talvez seja interessante você colocar pelo menos parte da sua base de dados onde existe essa "quantidade de dados diferentes". Abraço!

Comment: Imonferrari cada coluna tem em torno de 362-366 valores e são 30 acolunas. O que você sugere? Coloco o dput() todo? Seriam mais de 10.000 linhas.
Outra coisa, você já viu esse erro que relatei? Queria ao menos tentar entendê-lo para buscar uma solução.

Comment: Tentou como array? `as.array(sapply(dados1,summary))`.

Comment: Nunca tive esse erro... Minha sugestão é você disponibilizar o dataset em um serviço na nuvem por exemplo e compartilhar.

Comment: Imonferrari, tentei sua sugestão com o as.array(sapply(dados1,summary)) mas não deu certo, infelizmente! 

Deixo aqui o link para acesso aos dados, caso possa olhar: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12yA6GDYCc27MXPjexMXeLbvldplNG7k0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Você tem valores NA nesse dataset, utilize `dados1[is.na(dados1)] <- 0` ou insira a média, mediana... ou remova esses dados. Removendo/substituindo esses dados NA tudo deve funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa

```
  dados1 <- read.csv("dados-originais.csv", header = T, skip = 0, sep = ",")
  sum(is.na(dados1))
  dados1_summary <- data.frame(sapply(na.omit(dados1), summary))
```

1. Carregando os dados
2. Verificando a existencia de valores NA, neste caso existem 37
3. Omitindo os NA e gerando o data frame com sumário

Comment: Imonferrari, estou trabalhando com dados de precipitação, então não posso substituir por zero pois estaria considerando que naquele dia não houve chuva, sendo que na verdade não houve monitoramento. Eu precisaria desconsiderar esses NA's no summary(), teria alguma forma?

Comment: Talvez com `na.omit(dados1)`, dessa forma:`data.frame(sapply(na.omit(dados1), summary))` Ai você não precisa do: `dados1[is.na(dados1)] <- 0`

Comment: Imonferrari, funcionou! Agradeço muito! Que alívio e que aprendizado!

Comment: Por nada Bruna! Fico feliz que resolveu! Grande Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Eis uma forma razoavelmente simples.

```
dados1_summary <- lapply(na.omit(dados1), summary)
dados1_summary <- suppressWarnings(do.call(cbind, dados1_summary))
dados1_summary <- as.data.frame(dados1_summary)
```

Comment: Rui Barradas, quando executo o código que você sugeriu, no summary() aparece os Na's contabilizados, como se não tivesse desconsiderado-os. Quando você executou, apareceu os NA's quantificados ao final do summary?

Comment: @Bruna Tem razão, corrigido.

Comment: Rui Barradas deu certo! Obrigada por apontar uma outra forma de conseguir o que precisava.